# Как построить график используя колонки таблицы и индексы строк?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация, seaborn

у меня есть вот такая сгруппированная таблица где индексы строк - тарифы использующиеся пользователями. Колонки - месяца. А значения - медианная длительность звонков пользователей выборки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять каким образом я могу построить график по этой таблице, пытался используя seaborn сделать lineplot который будет отображать две линии:
1)Изменения длительности звонков в тарифе smart
2)Изменение длительности звонков в тарифе ultra

Но мои попытки не увенчались успехом в момент когда я попытался передать на ось X названия колонок

UPD: Если это поможет:
Изначально таблица выглядела вот так, это все звонки совершённые за год(около 300000 строк)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Потом я их сгруппировал по пользователям для решения другой задачи:

```
calls_duration_perMonth_data = calls_data.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='call_month', values='duration', aggfunc='sum')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И уже после этого группировал для подсчёта медианного/среднего:

```
calls_dur_allUsers = calls_duration_perMonth_data.groupby(by='tariff').median()
```

Comment: Наверное тут pivot надо сделать, чтобы получить столбец в значениях которого будут месяцы. А вообще покажите ваш код

Comment: Дополнил, расписал все преобразования в этой таблице, не исключаю что можно было это как-то сделать на основе изначальной таблицы

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример исходных данных (или выложите файл с данными на файлообменник, не требующий регистрации) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: У нас нет возможности использовать ваш пример данных если вы приводите его в виде картинки...

Comment: Таблицы с яндекс практикума, не уверен что их можно распространять таким образом
Есть идеи как мне можно поступить в этой ситуации?

Comment: @АндрейЧевозёров, в приведенной мною ссылке есть примеры создания исскуственных примеров данных... ;)

Comment: у вас все исходные данные за __один__ год?

Comment: @MaxU Да, все эти звонки совершены выборкой из 500 пользователей за 2018 год

Comment: *как мне можно поступить в этой ситуации?* - вам подсказали как поступить. Извините, но я ставлю минус за картинки данных в вопросе. Если вы поправите вопрос, то дайте мне знать коротким комментарием, чтобы я  мог отменить минус вопорсу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Создаем искусственный DataFrame для демонстрации решения:

```
N = 10**5
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": np.random.randint(500, size=N),
    "duration": np.random.randint(30, size=N),
    "call_date": np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=365, freq='D'), N),
    "tarif": np.random.choice(["smart", "ultra"], N)
})
```

получилось:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
        id  duration  call_date  tarif
0       54        26 2018-12-23  ultra
1      338        16 2018-08-17  smart
2      493        15 2018-10-12  ultra
3       83        28 2018-07-31  smart
4      343        19 2018-06-19  smart
...    ...       ...        ...    ...
99995  489         1 2018-10-09  ultra
99996  213        29 2018-01-01  smart
99997    3        18 2018-09-22  smart
99998  267        14 2018-02-21  smart
99999   85        16 2018-07-21  ultra

[100000 rows x 4 columns]
```

решение:

```
(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="MS", key="call_date"), "tarif"])
   .sum()
   ["duration"]
   .unstack()
   .plot(grid=True))

plt.tight_layout()
```

результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]